# Deny post request to specific file types

Tags: apache, .htaccess, post

i'm providing service which allow end user to upload thier files via application which use post request to send images and videos to my server ,

i'm trying to restrict/filter post request on Apache level and allow only images and video to proceed and drop other request carry different file type
i'm trying to do it via htaccess , any advise here or tips

> .htaccess example

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?:inc|php|py|rb)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

or is there better way ? mod_sec for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your setup but typically you use some type of backend language to handle the files you receive. However you can restrict the `POST` to certain file types using rewrite. I would put what I want to `Allow` instead listening every possible file type that I want to deny.

e.g. If I only want to `allow` PHP and python files for POST method I could do this.

```
RewriteEngine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|py)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Substitute the file types for yours.